# How can I programmatically make a specific cell enter the startEdit state?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-tableview

I have set up a `cellFactory` for the fourth column of the table and the key code for the `TableCell` is as follows:

```
@Override
public void startEdit() {
    super.startEdit();
    comboBox.setValue(getString());
    setGraphic(comboBox);
    comboBox.setPrefWidth(getTableColumn().getMinWidth());
}

@Override
public void cancelEdit() {
    super.cancelEdit();
    setGraphic(null);
    setText(getString());
}

private String getString() {
    return (getItem() == null) ? ""
                   : (Objects.equals(getItem(), EegLeadType.NONE_FOCUS_NAME) ? EegLeadType.NONE_NAME
                             : getItem());
}
```

How can I programmatically make a specific cell enter the `startEdit` state? For example, if I have selected a row in the table, I want the cell in the fourth column of that row to enter the `startEdit` state, without having to click on the fourth column.

[image]

Comment: Use the [`TableView#selectionModel`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TreeTableView.html#selectionModelProperty) property to react to a row being selected and [`TableView#edit(int,TableColumn)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#edit(int,javafx.scene.control.TableColumn)) to programmatically start the edit.

Comment: Also ensure the `TableView` is [`editable`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#editableProperty): "only if the TableView, the TableColumn (if applicable) and the TableCells within it are both editable will a TableCell be able to go into their editing state.".